# Message body reader for AsyncResponse

Tags: scala, asynchronous, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

I'm using async reposne feature of jersey in my resource

```
  @GET
  @Path("/{a}")
  @Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
  def asyncGet(@Suspended asyncResponse: AsyncResponse, @PathParam("a") a: Int): Unit = {
    someFuture.onSuccess(asyncResponse.resume(_))
  }
```

But when performing request to this resource I get

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse, and Java type interface javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found
```

I'm using grizzly as http server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in one custom library that transitivly was depended on jersey 1.x, but I'm using jersey 2.x in my project. So the problem solved